# Ag-grid bundle size is too big

Tags: angular, bundle, ag-grid, enterprise

I am developing a web application with Angular 6. I have an Ag-grid enterprise edition. Ag-grid documentation says, that we have to import all *ag-grid-angular*, *ag-grid-community*, and *ag-grid-enterprise* to work with Ag-grid enterprise.

After compiling, the total main bundle size crosses 1.5 MB. In that *ag-grid-community* is 694KB and *ag-grid-enterprise* is 230 KB:

[image: Bundle size image]

Is this the normal behavior of Ag-grid?

I am using Ag-grid version 19.0.0 and the following command for building:

```
ng build --prod --aot --build-optimizer --vendor-chunk=true
```

Comment: did you find any work around / solution .?

Answer (score 6):

This is something that we know and we have in our backlog

Project structure improvements  AG-1329 Reduce grid bundle size (via tree shaking)

You can see our pipeline here:

https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-pipeline/

Note that we don't have any plans to do any improvements any time soon given its comlexity, but we are hoping to eventually be able to provide with a small bundle

I would recommend that if you are a customer, that you contact ag-grid support directly for more information

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi. I'm not able to find the ticket you specified in the link, so I guess it has been added? If so, what version does include the bundle size reduced? I'm using enterprise version.

Answer (score 6):

There's an in-depth blog about this topic in the official documentation page.

[Minimising Bundle Size](https://blog.ag-grid.com/minimising-bundle-size/)

Basically, we use modules instead of packages. By doing so, we will include only what we need.

**E.x.**
This is a react example but main logic is same for angular and vue as well.

In your package.json, instead of this

```
"ag-grid-community": "^27.0.1",
"ag-grid-react": "^27.0.1",
```

use this

```
"@ag-grid-community/core": "^28.1.0",
"@ag-grid-community/react": "^28.1.0",
"@ag-grid-community/client-side-row-model": "^28.1.0",
"@ag-grid-community/styles": "^28.1.0",
```

and in your page, change your import from this

```
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';
```

to this

```
import { AgGridReact } from '@ag-grid-community/react';
import '@ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css';
import '@ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';

import { ModuleRegistry } from '@ag-grid-community/core';
import { ClientSideRowModelModule } from '@ag-grid-community/client-side-row-model';

ModuleRegistry.registerModules([
    ClientSideRowModelModule,
]);
```

Answer (score 2):

The item **AG-1329 Reduce grid bundle size** Alberto has quoted above has been implemented as part of ag-Grid v22, released in November 2019. This added the option to import ag-Grid via modules that contain different aspects of ag-Grid functionality. This allows you to only import the modules for the functionality you're actually using, thus decreasing the ag-Grid bundle size.

This approach is covered in detail and the list of modules you can import are shown here:
https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/javascript/modules/

We built a Vue project with ag-Grid to illustrate this approach using only the modules below:
**@ag-grid-community/core** and **@ag-grid-community/infinite-row-model**
Please download this sample Vue project here:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AljcY8dewwaBnFPXn7V9eNjNM-wX?e=h8TnD0

This sample project above has a bundle size of only 1.0MB compared to the 1.8MB for the full ag-Grid package using all the ag-Grid enterprise functionality.

You can verify the resulting bundle size by running the command below for the attached Vue project:
npm i && npm run build && npm run build:report

Please follow this approach to load only the ag-Grid modules you're using to reduce bundle size. You can see the full list of modules here:
https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/javascript/modules/