# How to exclude ag-grid from webpack bundle

Tags: webpack, ag-grid, webpack-4, ag-grid-react

Following the [webpack documentation about externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) and the example [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/#externalize-lodash), I am trying to exclude `ag-grid` and `ag-grid-enterprise` from my webpack bundle.

Below is the externals property from my `webpack.config.js` (`webpack` v4.28.3)

Each dependency below has been included in the **peerDependencies** section of my `package.json`

```
externals: {
  'ag-grid': 'ag-grid', // v18.1.1
  'ag-grid-enterprise': 'ag-grid-enterprise', // v18.1.1
  'ag-grid-react': 'ag-grid-react', // v18.1.3-beta.1
  'react': 'react', // v15.6.1
  'react-dom': 'react-dom', // v15.6.1
  'react-router-dom': 'react-router-dom', // v4.2.2
  'semantic-ui-react': 'semantic-ui-react', // v0.72.0
}
```

Using the BundleAnalyzer (`webpack-bundle-analyzer` v3.0.3), the size and content of my bundle before and after is changed for each dependency listed in my externals, except for `ag-grid` and `ag-grid-enterprise`.  All other dependencies have been excluded from my bundle **(including `ag-grid-react`)**.

I would expect both `ag-grid` and `ag-grid-enterprise` to be excluded from the bundle as well.

I am not sure if I am missing something or if this issue is related to *Project structure improvements AG-1329 Reduce grid bundle size (via tree shaking)* mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52827942/ag-grid-bundle-size-is-too-big) or if it is a webpack bundling issue.

Any insight would be much appreciated.